# Get attribute id of a button that is pressed which redirects to a different page, (need it on redirection page load)

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a survey app and I am using the template tag for each survey to promote re-use. I have one html file that I use for all the surveys and I populate them on runtime depending on which button is pressed to select the survey using their specific id.

Example:

```
<a href="SurveyTemplate.html" id = 'survey1'</a>
 <a href="SurveyTemplate.html" id = 'survey2'</a>
```

On surveyTemplate, I have inserted a piece of a script that includes

```
window.onload = function() {
 // event.target.id should be survey1 or survey2, is showing up undefined
    generateQuestionsAndAnswers(idToSurveyMap[event.target.id]); 

};
```

where generateQuestionAndAnswers is a function that populates the survey using from an array of survey data.

idSurveyMap is a map that maps the id's of the html element (string) to the survey data, which is an array.

The important idea that I have trouble with is getting the id of the link that is pressed. Event.target.id is giving me undefined. Am I not able to access it this way? Is there another way?

Comment: If a new page loads when you click the link, you will not be able to access the event in the next link. You could, however, format your links so that the survey number is the url itself, like `SurveyTemplate.html?num=1` or `SurveyTemplate.html#1`

Answer (score 0):

How about using a get parameter?

```
<a href="SurveyTemplate.html?id=1">survey1</a>
<a href="SurveyTemplate.html?id=2">survey2</a>
```

and

```
window.onload = function() {
    var surveyId = window.location.search.replace('?id=', '');
    generateQuestionsAndAnswers(idToSurveyMap[surveyId]); 
};
```